# Unable to set up scheduled refresh in powerBI Service when Data is imported into PowerBI from S3 using R script

Tags: powerbi, refresh, data-analysis, gateway, rscript

I have imported tables from S3 into PowerBi using the below R script:

```
``library(aws.s3)
Sys.setenv(
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = '',
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = '',
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = ''
)
data <- aws.s3::s3read_using(FUN = read.csv,
                             object = '',
                             bucket = '')
```

I am getting below error when I set up scheduled refresh :
Data source error: `{"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_GatewayUnreachable","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_GatewayUnreachable","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}` Table: raw_usage_measure.

The Gateway is up and running and is in the latest version.How to solve this?

I have imported tables from S3 into PowerBi using the below R script:

```
``library(aws.s3)
Sys.setenv(
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = '',
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = '',
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = ''
)
data <- aws.s3::s3read_using(FUN = read.csv,
                             object = '',
                             bucket = '')
```

I am getting below error when I set up scheduled refresh :
Data source error: `{"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_GatewayUnreachable","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Client_GatewayUnreachable","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}` Table: raw_usage_measure.

The Gateway is up and running and is in the latest version.How to solve this?

Expected Result: I was expecting to be able to refresh the data at 4 p.m. everyday.